# HTTP Post request in Marmalade C++

Tags: mysql, post, marmalade

I have a MySQL database set up to accept names through python as follows:

```
class PushNames(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    firstname = self.get_argument('firstname','')
    surname = self.get_argument('surname','')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    SQL = """insert into Names values ('""" + str(firstname) + """', '""" + str(surname) + """');"""
    cursor.execute( SQL )
    cursor.close()
```

I can add names to this using cURL as follows:

```
curl --data "firstname=John&surname=Smith" http://ip.address/pushnames
```

However I'm trying to achieve this using Marmalade's built in "IwHTTP.h". They're lacking in terms of examples, so I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to achieve this. This is their example code for performing a post request:

```
    theHttpObject->SetRequestHeader("Authorization", buf);
    theHttpObject->SetRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
    theHttpObject->SetRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5");
    theHttpObject->SetRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
    theHttpObject->SetRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "en-GB");
    theHttpObject->SetRequestHeader("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");

    if (theHttpObject->Post(HTTP_URI, NULL, 0, GotHeaders, NULL) == S3E_RESULT_SUCCESS)
        status = kDownloading;
```

If anything, it has just confused me more. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated. In case it helps, their HTTP class documentation can be found here: http://api.madewithmarmalade.com/classCIwHTTP.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. In case anyone ever needs it:

```
    theHttpObject = new CIwHTTP();
    theHttpObject->SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    char* msg = "firstname=John&surname=Smith";
    theHttpObject->Post(HTTP_URI, msg, strlen(msg), GotHeaders, NULL);
```